# Thread renaming in Silverlight Unit Tests

Tags: multithreading, silverlight, unit-testing

In my silverlight unit tests, I have several unit test methods of a single unit test class where in each method, I'm setting Thread.Name to some string. Now this should crash after the first one  because the Thread.Name can't be set after it has already been assigned, I have also checked that each test method runs on a thread with the same managed id as the others, so I'm confused why it isn't throwing an error, are the threads somehow "reset" after each unit test is run?

Comment: Which test runner are you using?

Comment: I'm using the Silverlight for Windows Phone unit test framework, set up exactly like this http://www.smartypantscoding.com/a-cheat-sheet-for-unit-testing-silverlight-apps-on-windows-phone-7

Answer (score 0):

So I guess you are using MSTest - **MSTest uses a fresh thread from a ThreadPool for each and every test** (It also creates a whole new test class for each test).
Although it is kinda slow, it ensures isolation of tests (which is even more important should you run them in parallel).

You (probably) shouldn't bother with shared state between tests, as each test should stand on its own...

Comment: I don't think I am, on this page, http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2009/03/asynchronous-testing/ he mentions that desktop unit test (I'm assuming that's mstest) uses a new thread and app domain for each unit test; however, it says that the silverlight unit test executes all unit tests in the main ui thread, which makes sense, but it doesn't explain what happens in between each unit test that lets me rename the thread over and over again.